# How to integrate ImageTargets sample of Vuforia into Android Studio project

Tags: vuforia

I am trying to integrate the ImageTargets sample of Vuforia into my project, but I can't find any specific steps on what should I do. Can someone help me? I am using a Mac computer. I downloaded the android SDK and the samples, but I don't know how to use them in my project.

Comment: hey, any success?

Comment: Yep, it's all done, thanks for asking!